# Terraform: Populate an object with reasonable, then partially override?

Tags: terraform

I am looking for a way to have a variable of type "object" (to force a certain structure), and then override certain parts. consider this variable declaration:

```
variable "prod_vpc" {
  type = object({
        name = string,
        region = string,
        single_nat_gw = bool,
        create = bool,
        supernet = string
    })

  default = {
    name = "PROD"
    region = "eu-central-1"
    single_nat_gw = true
    create = false,
    supernet = "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
}
```

in this case, i might want to have this in my auto.tfvars:

```
prod_vpc = {
    create = true,
    supernet = "10.0.8.0/24"
}
```

because all other values are good as they are. the only way i can think of is to do this is with type = map(string) and conditionals in a locals block, i.e.:

```
variable "vpc_defaults" {
  type = object({
        name = string,
        region = string,
        single_nat_gw = bool,
        create = bool,
        supernet = string
    })

  default = {
    name = "PROD"
    region = "eu-central-1"
    single_nat_gw = true
    create = false,
    supernet = "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
}


variable "prod_vpc" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {}
}
```

then

```
prod_vpc = {
    create = true,
    supernet = "10.0.8.0/24"
}
```

and then:

```
locals {
    create = coalesce(var.prod_vpc["create"], vpc_defaults.create)
}
```

(i haven't tried this, but i think something along these lines should work)

any other ideas for pre-defining defaults and only overriding when needed?

regards

ruben

Comment: with maps, there are also other ways (maybe merge?) but i would loose "type-safety"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you had used a plain map rather than object type, it would not have been possible to do this in this way, and the reasoning is set out in the docs [here](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#map-variables-no-longer-merge-when-overridden). It is suggested there that you should use `locals` instead to provide the defaults and then explicitly merge them.

Meanwhile, as noted by James Bardin in [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21838#issuecomment-504446376) related GitHub issue, the object keys are required in order to set a default. If you want those to be `null`, then you have to explicitly set them as such.

James added:

> You also have the option of setting the default as null (or not having a default, and requiring the caller set a value). In that case however, you need to avoid passing a null object into merge, which you can do using a condition or coalesce:
>
> ```
> merged_map_keys = merge(local.default_map_keys, coalesce(var.prod_vpc, {}))
> ```

It would be *nice* if you could do something like this:

```hcl
variable "prod_vpc" {
  type = object({
    name          = string,
    region        = string,
    single_nat_gw = bool,
    create        = bool,
    supernet      = string
  })
  default = {}
}

locals {
  default_map_keys = {
    name          = "PROD"
    region        = "eu-central-1"
    single_nat_gw = true
    create        = false,
    supernet      = "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
  merged_map_keys = merge(local.default_map_keys, var.prod_vpc)
}
```

Then you could call it with:

```hcl
prod_vpc = {
  create   = true,
  supernet = "10.0.8.0/24"
}
```

There is more info in the open [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21838) issue.

Comment: the variable declaration (with typed object and empty default) does  not work in 0.12 ... "This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint"

Comment: @rmalchow, I just tried and I agree. I saw [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21384#issuecomment-495265031) comment by Martin Aktins from 29 days ago, which suggests to me that this should work, and this might be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Since Terraform v1.3, you can use [Optional Object Type Attributes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes)!

So in your case, you could do something like this:

```
variable "prod_vpc" {
  type = object({
        name = optional(string, "PROD"),
        region = optional(string, "eu-central-1"),
        single_nat_gw = optional(bool, true),
        create = optional(bool, false),
        supernet = optional(string, "0.0.0.0/0")
    })
}
```

Note that you should/can remove the `default {}` section!